# What am I doing wrong to generate proper logon message?

Tags: python, quickfix

I'm pretty new in quickfix, I've tried to read a lot and learn as much as I've could. But I'm facing a weird problem which I've could fix but I cannot understand why it's not working as expected.

First, my venue requires username and password, so I add both to 35=A message. This is expected, what it's not expected it's having field 141 automatically set in logon message, even when in cfg file this is not included, or at least not on purpose. And similar to SenderSubID, TargetCompID and TargetSubID which are required to my venue and having included them in config file are not considered in automatically generated Logon. What I'm doing in a wrong way? Maybe I'm using an incorrect AppDataDictionary, maybe I should change it to customize? Not sure how to fix this in a more smart way instead of using toAdmin to customize a lot of message fields which should be properly generated before.

Code snippet to fix the problem I'm facing

```py
def toAdmin(self, message, sessionID):
        # Hook que corre antes de enviar un mensaje al servidor fix
        msg_type = fix.MsgType()
        message.getHeader().getField(msg_type)
        if msg_type.getString() is fix.MsgType_Logon:
            message.removeField(141)
            message.getHeader().setField(fix.StringField(34, "1"))
            message.getHeader().setField(fix.SenderSubID("351"))
            message.getHeader().setField(fix.StringField(1408, "T5.0"))
            message.getHeader().setField(fix.TargetCompID("XXX"))
            message.getHeader().setField(fix.TargetSubID("M3"))
            message.setField(fix.Username("xxxxxxx"))
            message.setField(fix.Password("xxxxxxx"))
```

This is my configuration file

```
[SESSION]
StartTime=00:00:00
SenderCompID=A899
SenderSubID=351
EndTime=00:00:00
ConnectionType=initiator
ApplVerID=9
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=9
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
TargetCompID=XXX
TargetSubID=M3
SocketConnectPort=xxxx
SocketConnectHost=xx.xx.xx.xx
SocketUseSSL=Y
SSLEnable=Y
HeartBtInt=20
ReconnectInterval=30
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
SSLValidateCertificates=Y
ResetSeqNumFlag=N
```

Thanks a lot for your help, any idea would be welcome.

Regards

Comment: The `ResetOn...` options can lead to a set tag 141 on the Logon message. Try removing these options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried to put them to N and Y and same result, but I've not tried removing reference. I will.

Answer (score 0):

I think appart of removing `ResetOn...` not much more can be done. I've researched for same request in other languages (c#, Java and c) and proposal solution is always which I did. So I assume this is the best approach :(

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: Actually I cannot say that there is a similar problem in QuickFIX/J. `141=Y` is only sent out if configured. Maybe this is a subtle bug in QuickFIX?!

Comment: No setting `ResetOn...` in config file removes reference to `141` tag, but rest of "problem" still appears  (Unable to automatically include using config file SenderSubID, TargetCompID and TargetSubID), so I appreciate your help, but at the end I have to customize Logon message in ToAdmin method :)

Comment: Pretty sure that QFJ does support it according to https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html. But other variants might not have support for that.

Comment: It looks like that. In official [quickfix documentation to c and python port](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html) , there is no refernece to `XXXSubsID`... It's quite weird that `TargetCompID` appears in config but it is not attended in my Logon message...